# mysqli prepare statement is not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been stuck on this mysqli statment for a while. I can't see what wrong with it and i can get the error to display so i can see where i am going wrong.

Can you please help me with this error or please explain to me how to display the error so I can fix it.

this is my code

```
$add_record = $db->prepare('UPDATE vehicles SET name= ?, VINnum= ?, maker= ?, model= ?, color= ?, year= ?, oilChange= ?, registrationExp= ?, insuranceExp= ?, dailyRate= ?, weekleyRate= ?, monthleyRate= ?, currentMillage= ?, oilChangeMillage= ?, licensePlate= ?, vehicleCost= ? WHERE Vehicles_id = ?');


            $add_record->bind_param('sssssisssdddsssdi', $name, $VIN, $maker, $model, $color, $year, $oilChange, $registration, $insurance, $dailyRate, $weekleyRate, $monthleyRate, $currentMillage, $changeOilMillage, $plate, $cost, $id);                      


            if( $add_record->execute() ){
                $pass_list = '<li>Good to go</li>'; 
            } else {
                $error_list .= '<li>SQL error</li>';
                echo $db->error;    
            }
```

Comment: Once you get the error using the change below, could you please let us know with an edit?

Answer (score 0):

to view the error, change

```
if( $add_record->execute() ){
                $pass_list = '<li>Good to go</li>'; 
            } else {
                $error_list .= '<li>SQL error</li>';
                echo $db->error;    
            }
```

to

```
if( $add_record->execute() ){
            $pass_list = '<li>Good to go</li>'; 
        } else {
            $error_list .= '<li>SQL error</li>';
            echo $add_record->error."<br/>";    // <--- this is what you need to change
            echo $db->error."<br/>";    // <--- this is what you need to change

        }
```

also don't forget to close the statment when you're done

```
$add_record->close();
```

also, depending on where you echo your error, it might not display on an html page.  to check for this, view your page source

Comment: To clarify, the `mysqli_stmt` and `mysqli` objects may contain completely different error information.  Therefore, it's best to check _both_ after any instantiation or execution of any method from either object.

Comment: neither one is displaying and errors! I don't see why it is not.

Comment: @Mike maybe your query is correct and there is no error but instead your 'where' condition in your query isn't matching any rows thus not updating anything...?

Comment: If there a way I can out put what why prepare statement generates on the screen so i can copy it and run in in phpmyadmin to see what kinds of error I get?

Comment: hmm not sure.  you can try echoing the prepared statement after the bind param statement?

Answer (score 0):

Oh My God, I hate these small error. I wasted  more that 5 hours on this error which was so simple. the file path in my action path in the form was pointed to the incorrect file and that's why I kept on getting this error.

Thanks guys for your time.